# unable to kill and exit a large insert query properly

Tags: mysql

I have a large insert into statement that takes a long time to complete, so I killed it, but then it just sitting on processlist with status killed, and then I'm unable to restart mysql properly.  I have to reboot.  It happens everytime.   please see log trace below.   How do I handle this kind of situation?

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+--------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User | Host               | db           | Command | Time | State  | Info                                                                                                 |
+----+------+--------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                        |
|  6 | root | 127.0.0.1:49971    | xxxxxx | Killed  |  826 | update | insert ignore into xxxxxx.xxxxxxs_tmp2 (xxxxxx, reshoot) values ('xxx.xxx',1),('0- |
|  7 | root | localhost          | xxxxxx | Query   |    0 | NULL   | show processlist                                                                                     |
+----+------+--------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
[root@x-xxx-x-xx ~]# service mysqld restart
mysqld: unrecognized service
[root@x-xxx-x-xx ~]# service mysql restart
Shutting down MySQL.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................... ERROR! 
 ERROR! Failed to stop running server, so refusing to try to start.
[root@x-xxx-x-xx ~]# service mysql status
 SUCCESS! MySQL running (4465)
[root@x-xxx-x-xx ~]# mysql -u root -xxxxx
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I'm guessing it's because it's trying to rollback all the rows that it inserted.  is this right?  here's the mysql error log:

```
110209 19:59:33 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
110209 19:59:34  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110209 20:09:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
110209 20:09:16 [Warning] options --log-slow-admin-statements, --log-queries-not-using-indexes and --log-slow-slave-statements have no effect if --log_slow_queries is not \
set
110209 20:09:16 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
110209 20:09:16  InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
110209 20:09:16  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 6.0G
110209 20:09:17  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110209 20:09:17  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
110209 20:09:19  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 16772431917
110209 20:09:20 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@xx-xxx-xx-xx' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
110209 20:09:20 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
110209 20:09:20 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.8'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
110209 20:13:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
110209 21:07:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
110209 21:07:08 [Warning] options --log-slow-admin-statements, --log-queries-not-using-indexes and --log-slow-slave-statements have no effect if --log_slow_queries is not \
set
110209 21:07:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
110209 21:07:08  InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
110209 21:07:08  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 6.0G
110209 21:07:09  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110209 21:07:10  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 16798669157
110209 21:07:11  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16803911680
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16809154560
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16813133382
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 219970 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 1400
110209 21:07:20  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 5\
0 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
110209 21:13:34  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 1200, 219970 rows to undo

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 1110209 21:13:34  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 16813133382
 2110209 21:13:34 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@xx-xxx-xx-xx' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
 3 4110209 21:13:35 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
110209 21:13:35 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.8'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 5.5, try using a delayed insert instead of insert.

> When you use KILL, a thread-specific
>   kill flag is set for the thread. In
>   most cases, it might take some time
>   for the thread to die because the kill
>   flag is checked only at specific
>   intervals:
>   [...]
>
> An INSERT DELAYED thread quickly
>   flushes (inserts) all rows it has in
>   memory and then terminates.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html

> The queued rows are held only in
>   memory until they are inserted into
>   the table. This means that if you
>   terminate mysqld forcibly (for
>   example, with kill -9) or if mysqld
>   dies unexpectedly, any queued rows
>   that have not been written to disk are
>   lost.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html